# Why smooth scrolling is works but only sometimes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using js code from w3school https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Add smooth scrolling to all links
      $("a").on('click', function(event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
          // Prevent default anchor click behavior
          event.preventDefault();

          // Store hash
          var hash = this.hash;

          // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
          // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 800, function(){

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        } // End if
      });
    });
</script>
```

But to my surprised I found that smooth scrolling works 6 out of 10 times. I cleared the cache of my browser but issue persists.
Why is this happening?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You just copy/paste the code from w3school so what is the problem ? It doesn't works on their website or in your website ? I have no problem using it

Comment: it doesnt work on mine sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to use just css

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_smooth_scroll

Comment: as well as do you have any supporting html?

Comment: heres a site that uses just css and html https://54x1.github.io/churchill/ and has smooth scrolling thou smooth scrolling css only works on updated browsers like supported by

Comment: yes i treid this. site has an existing top button that uses smooth scroll. so it slows down the existing smooth scroll when using css thats why i m not using it and using the js code instead. but js code works only for 6 out of 10 times.

Comment: this is an issue of fossasia,i tried to solve it with css but top scroll was delyaed thats why i tried with js..but as u can see sometimes it will work and sometimes it will not(if works then reload the page and you will find it not working)

Comment: pr link -https://github.com/fossasia/labs.fossasia.org/pull/412      it would be a great help if you would help me to find out my mistakes... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely caused by you, the user. You need to interrupt the scrolling on user interaction. Otherwise the scrolling animation continues whilst you are trying to do something else.

This is code I use, to interrupt scrolling when the user interrupts, by doing a scroll, click, select, or anything else that would normally stop a scroll.

*note: Even though this code is relatively stable I have found minor issues with it every now and then with different browsers, low performance mobile phones, etc.. Ideally you'd use the suggestion in [54x1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8224971/54x1)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561485/1356107) and use something like this as a fallback for [older/unssupported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior).*

```js
  /**
   * Select all links that contain a anchor reference
   */
  $('a[href^="#"]')
/**
 * Don't affect whatever is in this not selector.
 */
.not("[data-toggle]")
.on("click", function(event) {
  var $thislink = $(event.target);
  /**
   * where we want to move to. An anchor is a very handy id selector in once
   * so we only use the href attribute.
   */
  var $anchor = $($thislink.attr("href"));
  /**
   * No element with that id? return, let native behaviour take over(jump to anchor if exists)
   */
  if ($anchor.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  var stopfunction = function() {
    page.stop();
  };
  var page = $("html, body");
  /**
   * just trigger ONCE on any scroll interrupt event
   */
  page.one(
    "scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove",
    stopfunction
  );
  page
    /**
     *  Stop current scrolling on page.
     */
    .stop()
    /**
     * Animate scrolling to the desired section
     */
    .animate(
      {
        scrollTop: $anchor.offset().top
      },
      1000,
      function() {
        /**
         * unbind our one handler.
         */
        page.off(
          "scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove",
          stopfunction
        );
      }
    );
  /**
   * stop direct jumping to anchor(the default behaviour by browser)
   */
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
li {
   margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li id="hello"><a href="#world">hello</a></li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li>.</li>
   <li id="world"><a href="#hello">world</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: problem is not this. smooth scroll happens for 10 out of 6 times. eg - i opened the site and smooth scroll is working i refreashed it and it stop working on whole page , i again refreshed it and it started working.